# Resultset to array and return with method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, resultset

1. This is my code for database class method to get data in resultset and return an general array in this I have only one field in database.
2. Problem : I am not able to get the array abc[] and its contents and when I return it also says arrayIndexoutOfBond error "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

   ```
   public String[] getTableContents(String tableName) {
       ResultSet results = null;
       String[] abc = null;
       int a = 0;
       try {
           System.out.println(conn);
           stmt = conn.createStatement();
           results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
           ResultSetMetaData rsmd = results.getMetaData();
           // int numberCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
           for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
               // print Column Names
               System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i) + "\t\t");
           }
           System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------");

           while (results.next()) {
               System.out.println(results.getString(2) + " 1");
               String em = (results.getString(2));
               System.out.println(em + " 2");
               abc = em.split(" ");
               System.out.println(abc + " 3");
           }
           results.close();
           stmt.close();

       } catch (SQLException suresh) {
           System.out.println(suresh);
       }
       System.out.println(abc + " 4");

       return abc;
   }
   ```

Comment: What line causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: You're not giving nearly enough information. What is this record in the database? Does it contain spaces (so what do you expect from `em.split(" ")`)? What is your output? Can you show the stack trace? I suspect that the exception even occurs *outside* this function, because you do something like `someVar = getTableContents(...);  someVar[1] ...`.